# Java: Converting CSV values to an EDF file

Tags: java, csv, european-data-format

I have a CSV file which needs to be converted into an EDF file using java. 
The CSV file contains 4 columns by 324 rows, each having decimal numbers as values. The 4 columns shows the 4-channels of the EEG. The rows show the data read each second.

As an edf file model, I am using an edf file created from EDF browser. Using EDF browser I converted the CSV into edf file and it works correctly. Now, I am trying to built that conversion using Java.

Until now, I have read the values from the CSV file. 
Also, I have build the header of the EDF file as required.
The only problem is that I have decimal values inserted but the model EDF file has different values.

However, when the model EDF file is open by notepad, the values are converted in some other format which I cannot understand.

Below is an image of the model EDF file with strange values. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWxcb.png)

If anyone could help me, either find another way to write the EDF file using java or convert the decimal values of the CSV file into this format in order to be read by the EDF browser app.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see the example in this link http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php.This link did not show converting value from csv to edf.but it shows converting value from one csv to another csv.You can refrence this link and you can write similar code for edf file.

Comment: EDF files are not viewable in notepad, try an edf file viewer.

Comment: I used EDF browser to check the signals. However, I used notepad to view the contents of the EDF file. Do you suggest any other reader ?
Thanks